# Is this the correct way to AND two signals?

Tags: vhdl

```
ARCHITECTURE
    SIGNAL in_adc_1 : unsigned(0 DOWNTO 0)  := (OTHERS => '0');
    SIGNAL in_adc_2 : unsigned(0 DOWNTO 0)  := (OTHERS => '0');

    BEGIN PROCESS -- counter_4_bit
        var count : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  
        IF (in_adc_1 = '1' and in_adc_2 ='1') THEN
            var_AddVoltage_ch16 <=  count + 1;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE rtl;
```

Comment: Think this is a better way of doing the if statement: IF (in_adc_1 and in_adc_2 := 1) THEN
       var_AddVoltage_ch16 <=  count + 1;
    END IF;

Comment: Just to point out: You instance a local variable 'count' in the process and then use it without previous assignment. (But it may be that you shortened the code to ask the question)

Comment: Why are you using one bit unsigned vectors instead of `bit` or `std_logic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the process being clock driven the counter will probably not work as expected.

```
ARCHITECTURE
-- Change to std_logic here unless you really need it the other way for some reason
SIGNAL in_adc_1 : std_logic;
SIGNAL in_adc_2 : std_logic;

BEGIN PROCESS -- counter_4_bit
    var count : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  
    -- Synchronize your counter
    IF rising_edge(clk) THEN
        IF (in_adc_1 = '1' and in_adc_2 ='1') THEN
            var_AddVoltage_ch16 <=  count + 1;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE rtl;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not clear to me why you are using `unsigned` type for one bit vectors. Nevertheless, your `if` statement will generate a compile-time error if you write it that way. The correct way of writing the same `if` statement using `unsigned` type will be,

```
IF (in_adc_1 = "1" and in_adc_2 = "1") THEN
```

The `"1"` (in double quotes) here represents *a vector of only one bit*.

The second `if` statement provided by you in the comments section reads 
`IF (in_adc_1 and in_adc_2 := 1)`. Again this will have to be modified in the following way, for the statement to compile correctly.

```
IF ((in_adc_1 and in_adc_2) = "1") THEN
```

Both ways of AND-ing are correct as far as the compile tools are concerned.

However, you could use the types `std_logic` or `bit` to achieve the same functionality (as pointed out in the comments). In this case the above `if` statement should be re-written as,

```
IF (in_adc_1 = '1' and in_adc_2 = '1') THEN
```

or as

```
IF ((in_adc_1 and in_adc_2) = '1') THEN
```

The `'1'` (in single quote) is *a single bit* when the signal is of type `std_logic` or `bit`.

Note: In VHDL, `:=` is used for variable assignments or for providing initial values